# Compare nullable Integer to 0

Tags: java

How we *must* compare an int wrapper, Integer, to zero value? We can use Integer when the int value can be null (int does not allows null):

```
Integer x;
```

both options throw java.lang.NullPointerException:

`0 == x;`   or    `x == 0;`

So, simple, how we can compare Integers that can or not, be null?

Comment: `Integer.valueOf(0).equals(x)` or `x != null && x == 0`

Comment: `Objects.equals(x, 0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` is a field in your class, so when you create it without making it to reference to any `Integer` object (`Integer x = new Integer(7)` for example), the compiler gives it a `null` for you (**the default values for Object references**). It seems like you have hence: `Integer x = null;`

So to compare it just use the `equals()` method that is implemented by Integer wrapper class.

```
new Integer(0).equals(x)
```

Comment: You should almost never call the `Integer` constructor. Use `Integer.valueOf()` instead.